# JQuery input on change, ajax sending request to laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to load a message about a person when his id is inputted without reloading the page. the problem is the data to be retrieved isn't being displayed. I am using Laravel framework, and JQuery but am not very familiar with JQuery and how laravel handles AJAX data (maybe that's why am stuck).

my html page

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="national_id" id="national_id" placeholder="Enter National Id Number">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<p class="text-success" id="person"></p>
<p class="text-danger" id="error"></p>
</div>
```

my Js document

```
$("#national_id").change(function(){

    var message = null;
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./getPerson",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            message = "Person: " + data['fName'] + " from " + data['village'];
            document.getElementById("person").innerHTML = message;

        },
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Error occurred";
        }
    });
});
```

my controller function

```
public function getPerson(Request $request){
        $nationalId = 123456;
        //$nationalId = $request->input('national_id');

        $person = Person::find($nationalId)->get(['fName','initials','lName','dob','village'])->toJSON();


        return $person;
    }
```

when i input the national id, i am only getting the "error occurred" message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just make sure that you indeed get some response

```
$person = Person::findOrFail($nationalId)->get(['fName','initials','lName','dob','village'])->toJSON();
```

Next, should be a on change function, also impacted by what version of jquery you are using

```
$("#national_id").on('change', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when that happens, it's related to an error in your backend function with Laravel. In Eloquent, in order to retrieve the model with find and a specific columns, you should use:

Person::find($nationalId, ['fName','initials','lName','dob','village'])

or

Person::select(['fName','initials','lName','dob','village'])->find($nationalId);

And it should be working now.